# Prove or disprove: If $a_n$ is Cauchy, is $\lfloor a_n \rfloor$ Cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences, ceiling-and-floor-functions

So all the posts explaining this were above my understanding or had conflicting answers, namely these two answers to the same posts where:

(1) implies if $a_n$ converges to $l$, then $\lfloor a_n \rfloor$ converges to $\lfloor l \rfloor$ ([link to said answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3383084/989186))

(2) implies if $a_n$ converges to $l$ where **(CASE 1)** if $l\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $\lfloor a_n \rfloor$ converges to $\lfloor l \rfloor$ but **(CASE 2)** if $l\in\mathbb{Z}$, then the sequence can "flit" above and below $l$ and following $\lfloor l \rfloor$ it would flip between $l$ and $l-1$ and if therefore nonconvergent and not Cauchy. (or at least that seems to be the implication for me) ([link to said answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3383105/989186))

Now I'm still quite new to real analysis but (2) does make sense to why it would be the case. If I could get some sort of confirmation to be sure I'm not being led astray that would be great. And if there are any functions that fit this, I would love to see them.

Comment: Which posts seem conflicting to you? Also, the second post makes no reference to the rational numbers ($\mathbb{Q}$). Do you mean the real numbers ($\mathbb{R}$) (i.e., the rational and *ir*-rational numbers). Both answers state that different things happen when $l$ is exactly an integer and when it isn't. This should be fairly easy to see if you observe that $a_n = 1-1/n$ approaches $1$ but has a floor of $\lfloor a_n \rfloor = 0$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not even true that a *continuous* function maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences, and $x\mapsto\lfloor x\rfloor$ is not even continuous!

A very simple counterexample is this:

> Let $a_n:=1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. $a_n\to1$ is clear, but: $$\lfloor a_n\rfloor=\begin{cases}0&n\text{ is odd}\\1&n\text{ is even}\end{cases}$$So $\lfloor a_n\rfloor$ is not Cauchy.

Note that $\Bbb Z\subseteq\Bbb Q$ so your second paragraph doesn't really make sense. Did you mean: If $\ell\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, then $\lfloor a_n\rfloor\to\ell$? So long as $\ell$ is not an integer, then $\lfloor a_n\rfloor\to\ell$ *is* guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you for the example! And yeah I should've written $l\in\mathbb{Q}-\mathbb{Z}$ or something along those lines indeed.